# How to bind value and event kendo slider and kendo observable class

Tags: model, slider, kendo-ui, observable

I was trying to bind input box to kendo slider and this how lead me. If you have better way on implementing a requirement like this please share also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="testID" class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="">Weekly Rent Amount($)</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div data-role="rangeslider"
             data-min="1"
             data-max="1000"
             data-smallstep="5"
             data-largestep="10"
             data-tickplacement="both"
             data-bind="value: rent, events:{change: rentOnChange}">
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <input data-bind="value: rentMin, events:{change: rentOnChange}" />
        <input data-bind="value: rentMax, events:{change: rentOnChange}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

SCRIPT

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    sliderValue: 5,
    rentMin:"",
    rentMax:"",
    rent:function(){
        return [this.get("rentMin"),this.get("rentMax")]
    },
    rentOnChange:function(e){
        if(typeof e.values==="undefined"){
            this.set("rent",[this.get("rentMin"),this.get("rentMax")])
        }else{
            var rentval = e.values;
            this.set("rentMin",rentval[0]);
            this.set("rentMax",rentval[1])
        }


    }
});
kendo.bind($("#testID"), viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

HTML:

```
<div id="testID" class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="">Weekly Rent Amount($)</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div data-role="rangeslider"
             data-min="1" data-max="1000"
             data-smallstep="5" data-largestep="10"
             data-tickplacement="both"
             data-bind="value : rent">
            <input/>
            <input/>
        </div>
        <input data-bind="value: rent[0]"/>
        <input data-bind="value: rent[1]"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The differences are

1. `data-bind` definition for the `RangeSlider` that is `rent` (no event handlers needed)
2. `data-bind` definition for the two auxiliary `input` that now are `rent[0]` and `rent[1]`.

About the JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    rent: [ 323, 600 ]
});
kendo.bind($("#testID"), viewModel);
```

No explanation needed! :-)

Simple and elegant, don't think so?

Comment: I was doing this one but the problem is, i want that if i type value in the text box the slider value will also change.